# How do I loop bootstrapping function and add results to a table?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have two tables of data - the first is a full dataset with replicates (density) for one factor (habitat):

```
Table1 <- data.frame(
Habitat = sample(c("Woodland", "Grassland"), 10, replace = TRUE),
Density = sample(1:10)
)
```

The second is a summarized version, with one row per habitat containing the median density.

```
library(dplyr)
Table2 <-ddply(Table1, "Habitat",summarise, Median = median(Density))
```

I've got the code below to get bootstrapped confidence intervals (using data in table 1)......

```
fun.boot <- function(x, i) {median(x[i])}
Wood.boot <- boot(data = Table1$Density[Table1$Habitat=="Woodland"],statistic = fun.boot, R = 10000)
boot.ci(boot.out = Wood.boot, conf = 0.95, type = c("perc"))
```

I would like to put this data into the corresponding (habitat = woodland) row of table 2, but can only figure out how to do it by hand using the following (same for upperCI).....

```
Table2$LowerCI <- rep("NA",nrow(Table2))
Table2$LowerCI[Table2$Habitat == "Woodland"] <- 2
```

I have hundreds of runs to do (lots of habitats for lots of species), so i wonder if there is a way to automate this - i.e.

1. generate the confidence intervals for each habitat using a for loop or something
2. then read it into table 2??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare space for the result (note: you don't need quotes around `NA`):

```
Table2$LowerCI <- rep( NA, nrow(Table2) )
Table2$UpperCI <- rep( NA, nrow(Table2) )
```

Now you can loop over your habitats and store the results into the appropriate columns:

```
for( hab in Table2$Habitat )
{
  hab.boot <- boot(data = Table1$Density[Table1$Habitat==hab],statistic = fun.boot, R = 10000)
  hab.ci <- boot.ci(boot.out = hab.boot, conf = 0.95, type = c("perc"))
  Table2$LowerCI[Table2$Habitat==hab] <- hab.ci$percent[4]
  Table2$UpperCI[Table2$Habitat==hab] <- hab.ci$percent[5]
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Bit frustrated I didn't get the for loop but I was a bit baffled by the last bit!